# Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix. Prove that $A$ and $A^T$ have the same eigenvalues. Hint: Consider the characteristic equation

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is a homework question, so I am looking more for hints than a direct answer.

In addition, I know how to solve for eigenvalues, and google is telling me that is what a characteristic equation is/does, but I am still unsure of exactly what it is. Is it the equation you get after you take the determinant of the matrix you create and set it = to 0?

Thanks.

Comment: The characteristic equation is the equation that you solve to find the eigenvalues, i.e., $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$.

Comment: Note that the question should not be in the tile (or at least repeated in the main text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Theorem.** If $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, then $A$ is similar to $A^{\top}$. (Try to find out what meaning we assign to "similar").

**Theorem.** The determinant function is multiplicative.

The statement under consideration follows from these two theorems:
If $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, then there is some invertible $Q$ such that $A = Q^{-1}A^{\top}Q$, implying that
$$
\det (A^{\top} - \lambda I) = \det (Q^{-1}(A^{\top} - \lambda I)Q) = \det (A - \lambda I)
$$
for all scalars $\lambda$.

Answer (score 3):

$ P_{\lambda}(A^{T})=\det(\lambda I_{n}-A^{T})= \det((\lambda I_{n}-A)^{T})= P_{\lambda}(A) $

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a hint, then: What’s the relationship between the determinants of $A$ and $A^T$?

Comment: They are the same right?

Comment: That’s correct. One of the other answers uses this fact to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Eigenvalues of a matrix A are those values,say $\lambda$ which satisfy the equation $\det(\lambda I_{n}-A)=0$. This equation is called the characterstic equation.But we can see that the characterstic equations for $A$ and $A^{T}$ are the same and hence,their eigenvalues. Just try seeing how their characterstic equations are same.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Let $|M|$ denote the determinant of matrix $M$. Then
$$|A-xI|=|(A-xI)^T|= |A^T-xI|.$$